# How to align teaser images?

Tags: media, nodes

Is it possible to align (left or right) teaser images that are uploaded through Imagefield in Drupal 7? Is there a clean solution whithout hacking into drupal code?

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS to style your content. This happens in the theme of your site. The handbook on Drupal.org has a lot of documentation on how this is done.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way(If you did not "hack" any theme template files.):

```
.node-teaser .field-item img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

(You can change float[left/right] and margin-right/left values as you need.)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) or even better [Fences](http://drupal.org/project/fences) to assign CSS class to your teaser image or its container and then style that selector in CSS. Class assignment will be done on admin UI side, so the only code invloved will be CSS added to your theme.